# Counting total score after a certain number of turns

Tags: r

I have a situation where there is a coin flipping game. You start with $5 and each turn you win $1 or lose $1 with probability 0.5. I want to find out : over 20 turns - at each individual turn, what is the probability that you have 0 dollars or less?

I want to manually enumerate all possible game outcomes at each turn and count the probability manually.

Here is my logic:

Set up the problem:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

initial_amount <- 5
outcomes <- c(-1, 1)  

df <- data.frame(turn_number = integer(), score = numeric())
```

Start counting outcomes and scores at each turn:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
  combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), i))
  
  calculate_score <- function(row) {
    initial_amount + sum(row)
  }
  scores <- apply(combinations, 1, calculate_score)
  
  df_turn <- data.frame(turn_number = rep(i, length(scores)), score = scores)
  
  df <- rbind(df, df_turn)
}
```

Perform analysis to count percent of games at each turn where you have negative scores:

```
df_summary <- df %>%
  group_by(turn_number) %>%
  summarise(positive_score_percent = sum(score > 0) / n() * 100,
            negative_score_percent = sum(score <= 0) / n() * 100)
```

And finally, plot results:

```
ggplot(df_summary, aes(x = turn_number, y = positive_score_percent)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
labs(title = "Percentage of Positive Scores Over Turns",
     x = "Turn Number",
     y = "Percentage of Positive Scores") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(df_summary$turn_number)) +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Is what I have done correct? The behavior at the start of the graph seems logical - in the first 5 turns, its impossible to have negative score, so this is correct. But I would have thought at the end of the graph, I would have thought that the probability of positive score should always go down, but its not?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is running correctly, I've checked the first few results by setting `initial_amount=1`.  Notice that you haven't included a stopping condition, if you hit $0, you can return to +$1 the following turn.

After an odd number of turns, you will always have an even amount of money: after one turn, either $4 or $6, after three turns either $2, $4 or $6.  It is impossible to have an odd amount of money on an odd turn.

After 19 turns, there is a group with a $0, but no-one with a score of -$1 or +$1.  On turn 20, the group with $0 will be split, half return to positive scores and half stay zero or less.  Some individuals return to the positive group, but no individuals enter the negative/zero group.

This is true on every even turn.  The probability of being zero or less will always increase on the odd turns and decrease on the even turns (while tending towards fifty percent).

Try calculating it by hand, with `initial_amount=1` and you'll very quickly see the pattern.

In the limit, as the number of turns gets very large, your starting score matters less and less, and your probability of being above zero is determined by behaviour of the game.  As you are just as likely to increase and decrease your score, the long-run probability of having a positive score is 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers are correct.
The fact that the probabilities are not strictly decreasing is a result of the fact that you allow to continue playing after the player hits `amount = 0`.

Compare the results for `turn_number = 5` and `turn_number = 6`:

- in order to lose in 5 turns you need to hit `-1` five times out of five. The probability for that is `(1/2)^5`.
- In order to lose in 6 turns you need to hit `-1` six times out of six, which is more unlikely. The probability for that is `(1/2)^6`. Note that according to your rules if you get five times `-1` and one time `1` you end up with 1$ and hence you do not lose after six rounds (although you possibly already lost in 5 rounds).

Anyway, there is more efficient way to compute the probabilities using the binomial
distribution function `pbinom`:

```
neg_sc_pc <- numeric()
for (turn_number in 1:20) {
  neg_sc_pc[turn_number] <- pbinom((turn_number - 5L)/2, size = turn_number, prob = 0.5)
}
```

Note that `(turn_number - 5L)/2)` is the maximum number of +1 outcomes you need to lose a game in `turn_number` turns.

This way you can simulate far more than 20 rounds. In fact it seems like the probability of losing osciliates between `0.4887` and `0.4858`  for large `turn_number`